# Coredata concurrency with GCD and childcontext has invalid access/inaccessible CDSnapshot_Entity

Tags: ios, multithreading, core-data, concurrency, grand-central-dispatch

I'm trying to create a background thread that generates random financial data. It uses a childMOC and blockandwait to make insertions and saves.
It generally works but there are occasional crashes especially with bigger data sets. I'm guessing that it might be because of memory allocation/deallocation issues?

Any thoughts on what I'm doing wrong?

1. Declaration of main context

   ```
   lazy var managedObjectContext: NSManagedObjectContext? = {
   let coordinator = self.persistentStoreCoordinator
   if coordinator == nil {
       return nil
   }
   var managedObjectContext = NSManagedObjectContext(concurrencyType: .MainQueueConcurrencyType)
   managedObjectContext.persistentStoreCoordinator = coordinator
   return managedObjectContext }
   ```
2. Get a copy of MainMOC and create PrivateMOC for background writing

   `let mainMOC = (UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate).managedObjectContext
   let privateMOC = NSManagedObjectContext(concurrencyType: .PrivateQueueConcurrencyType)
       privateMOC.parentContext = mainMOC`
3. Main function that calls threading

   ```
   iDataManager.setupManager()
   iDataManager.preloadDatabase()
   //3. load data from coreData
   iDataManager.loadListing()

   //TODO: swap in load code
   let loaderQueue = dispatch_queue_create("com.invest.serial.queue", DISPATCH_QUEUE_SERIAL)

   dispatch_async(loaderQueue, {
       //does not account for the market listing
       for var index = 0; index < self.iDataManager.dmStockListings.count; ++index {
           self.iDataManager.preloadPrice(index)

           dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
               self.loadingViewController.updateProgressIndicator(index, total: self.iDataManager.dmStockListings.count)
           })

       }
       dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
           self.loadingViewController.progressLabel.text = "Loading Done!"
           self.iDataManager.saveChanges()

           //5. init viewControllers as Panels
           AppSettings().delay(0.2, closure: {
               self.setupViewControllers()
           })
        })
   })
   ```
4. Generate prices and call privateMOC block

   ```
       let currentStock : MOStockListing
           currentStock = dmStockListings[index]
   ```

   //declared as var dmStockListings : [MOStockListing] = [] and contains all MOStockListing from the mainContext

   ```
   var error : NSError?
   var stockPrices : [MOPrice] = []
   var price : MOPrice

   //check coredata if there are prices
   var fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "MOPrice")
   let sortDescriptor = NSSortDescriptor(key: "priceDate", ascending: true)
   fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [sortDescriptor]

   let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "stock == %@", currentStock)
   fetchRequest.predicate = predicate

   stockPrices = privateMOC?.executeFetchRequest(fetchRequest, error: &error) as! [MOPrice]

   if stockPrices.count == 0 {
       //create daily, weekly and monthly
       //set flag for update
       dmDatabaseState = .UpdateFlag

       privateMOC.performBlockAndWait({

           self.generateDemoPrices(currentStock)

           var errorPointer = NSErrorPointer()
           self.privateMOC.save(errorPointer)

       })

   }
   ```
5. Generate Price function: Iterates thru 1000 days to create random values. Also makes an insertion in mainMOC. generally works. But should I be using privateMoc instead?

   ```
               //load prices
           price = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName("MOPrice", inManagedObjectContext: privateMOC!) as! MOPrice

           price.setValue(close, forKey: "priceClose")
           price.setValue(high, forKey: "priceHigh")
           price.setValue(open, forKey: "priceOpen")
           price.setValue(low, forKey: "priceLow")
           price.setValue(volume, forKey: "priceVolume")
           price.setValue(dateValue, forKey: "priceDate")
           price.setValue(change, forKey: "priceChange")

           price.stock = currentStock
   ```

Comment: I'm thinking I need to have privateMOC load all the entities by itself and perform the insertions then call for a save. Being a child of mainMOC, I shouldn't need to make any context merges, is that correct?

Edit: that seems to work. I also found that keeping additional processing on the main thread made load times faster. I used the privateMOC.blockandwait for only writing to the coredata. 
I revised the code above to reflect this.